# Resampling 30 m NDVI to 5 m in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi, resampling

Is there any easy way to resample 30 meter NDVI from Landsat 8 images to 5 metres?

I use raster to point and the interpolation of point to raster using Kriging method.

I know that it may not be a proper way of  getting 5 m NDVI but for the purpose of demonstration I need to do.

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] to see that there should be only one question asked per question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Resample Tool* it is in the *Data Management Toolbox*. [See here](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00170000009t000000) for ESRI documentation.

Additionally there are instructions on how to apply pan-sharpening with a lower resolution band on ESRI documentation [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009t000000mz000000). In a nutshell you will use the Pan-sharpening section of the Symbology tab of the raster layer, see image below:

[image: Pan-sharpening section of Symbology tab of raster layer]

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have tried this method of resampling more than 30 times and the result is the same and the raster appears 30m again, also I considered that pan sharpening  with the method you mentioned above can be done with an image with 3 bands at least , NDVI has only one band, there most be other method, I tried using image analysis toolbar, it does but it changes the values of NDVI.

Comment: If you resample a NDVI down to 5m from 30m it will appear as though it is 30m as all of the values within each 5m cell within the 30m cell block will still have the same value as the original 30m cell. However the cell size should be 5m.

Comment: Is there anything particular in Environmental tab to change? I  change cell size...and tried different options as well, as you said if you measure the pixel size should be 5 meter, but surprisingly it appears again 30 meters...

Comment: What is the value of _Cell Size (X, Y)_  on the _Source_ tab of the _Layer Properties_ dialog for the raster layer that is output from the resample tool?

Comment: the output in layer properties is 5 meter, but when I measure the pixel size on screen, it is still 30 meter.

Comment: The layer properties are correct, it is 5m resolution. However, because every 5m cell within the original 30m block has the same value you are unable to differentiate between the individual 5m cells. Check the value of  _Columns and Rows_ on the same _Source_ tab of the _Layer Properties_ and compare it with the original 30m raster.